# which javascript files are NOT being used on page load

Tags: javascript, pageload

Is it possible to find out which javascript files are NOT used on a web page without having to add console logs or debug or removing them to see if things break?

I'm looking for a tool, or a command line script or firefox plugin etc.

For example, let's say I have these included in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/something.js"></script>
```

On the page, calls are only made to functions in `functions.js`, `validation.js` and `jquery.js`. How can I know that `something.js` is not used and therefore can be safely removed from the header?

I've tried rooting through things like FireBug, chrome's console, yslow and server logs, but these all tell me which scripts have been loaded, i.e. all of them, not which ones have been used.

Comment: Is there any such tool/method now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no simple "this file is in use / not in use" detection mechanism, because there are so many ways to call, extend and reference things in JavaScript.

There are dozens of ways to call a function, e.g. in the `click` event of an element, `eval()` statements... You could be extending the prototype of an existing class in a script file... etc. Also, you could be fetching new markup through AJAX than in turn references functions from a certain include, something impossible to test for automatically without fetching the content.

Unless somebody comes up with a tool that tackles exactly this (I'm not saying it's  impossible, just that it is horribly hard) I'd say working this out manually with a good IDE and search function is the best way to go about it.

Comment: If Firebug from FireFox and Developers Tools from Chrome can tell which CSS is being used and which is not then why not JS. Hope they will soon add this feature.

Comment: @bjan it's not as simple to do for JS as it is for CSS. You would have to catch every state change that is caused by a JS file, eg. variable definitions etc. It would require a lot of work on the Developer tools' side.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to my own question getting on for 7 years later, Chrome dev tools now has exactly this feature! https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage

Comment: if you have any popup in your page which is hidden on page load and css used for that popup will be considered as unused css. This tool is also no exact and perfect but somehow identify the first page load required css

Answer (score 1):

Only took 7 years :) Also wanted to point out that you can automate this with Navalia: https://github.com/joelgriffith/navalia.

Here's a quick example:

```
import { Chrome } from 'navalia';
const chrome = new Chrome();

async function checkCoverage() {
  await chrome.goto('http://joelgriffith.net/', { coverage: true });
  const stats = await chrome.coverage('http://joelgriffith.net/main.bundle.js');
  console.log(stats); // Prints { total: 45913, unused: 5572, percentUnused: 0.12135996340905626 }
  chrome.done();
}

checkCoverage();
```

More here https://joelgriffith.github.io/navalia/Chrome/coverage/.

Answer (score 0):

Coming at this from a different direction, you could look into using (lazy) loading javascript libraries. I couldn't say how appropriate this would be in your situation, but I have seen mention of these two in the last week, but haven't used either of them:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lazy (only for lazy loading of jQuery plugins?)
- http://labjs.com/ (not sure if this does lazy loading?)