# How I determine the javascript files which work on the elements on the page?

Tags: javascript, performance

I bought a theme and the home page was having a lot of elements which need a lot of JavaScript files, but after I modify the theme and delete some of its elements I think I am no longer need all these files included in the modified pages so I ask if any automatic tool to know the file already have a real role in the page

Comment: Can you post more specific details about your website or the theme? Without any code or specific details there is no way of knowing which JS files are necessary.

Comment: I can check them one by one, but it will take a lot of time and the process may have some mistakes like canceling the including of a file I don't notice its effect on any elements so I will delete it because I will think it's useless for me . so I ask if any automatic tool to do this job ?

Comment: Checking them one by one is probably your best bet if you are not able to post information about the code or the template. Is your website live on the web?

Comment: still in developing , and i work on local host

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which javascript files are NOT being used on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100040/which-javascript-files-are-not-being-used-on-page-load)